# apt-get install unable to locate package on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to install matplotlib on my ubuntu 12.04 system with python3. I've read that this package should be available in the package manager, but when I type

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

I get

```
 E: Unable to locate package python3-matplotlib
```

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and I still get the error. I know this is a simple problem, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/388541/e-unable-to-locate-package-update-when-i-try-to-update-my-system-why) out. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: If you can you should upgrade to saucy or trusty, then `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the package does not exist, see:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=matplotlib&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all

If you need matplotlib + python3 on 12.04 you will probably have to install it from source.

Answer (score 0):

As tcaswell pointed out, it doesn't seem to be included in the official Ubuntu repos. You could try to find an external repo for it, but I think you'll be better off installing the version from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/1.3.1).

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Most people prefer to install python dependencies using a tool like pip, which defaults to the PyPI repo for downloads.

You could also install from source but then upgrading can become tricky. On the other hand for most packages PyPI will receive updates well before they work their way down to a distro's repo.